# Scala REPL startup error "class file is broken"

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

Every time after starting Scala 2.9.2 REPL (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0-ea) first line of code executing bring me an error:

```
scala> 1 + 2
error: error while loading CharSequence, class file '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar(java/lang/CharSequence.class)' is broken
(bad constant pool tag 15 at byte 1484)
```

Later during further evaluation in current REPL instance no similar errors are occured.

Has anyone any suggestion how to handle this behaviour?

Comment: I think this is because of some conflicts between Scala 2.9.2 and Java 8, try to use newer Scala or older Java

Comment: Thanks for advise. Switch to Scala 2.10.2 has solved the problem.

Comment: I am using Scala  2.11.8 -- Copyright 2002-2016, LAMP/EPFL and java version "1.8.0_111"--->     Then also I am getting following errors:                                              [INFO] No known dependencies. Compiling everything
[ERROR] error: error while loading CharSequence, class file '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar(java/lang/CharSequence.class)' is broken
[INFO] (class java.lang.RuntimeException/bad constant pool tag 18 at byte 10)
[ERROR] one error found

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try to select other alternative provider java:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

There are some choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

```
  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java          1071      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1061      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1051      manual mode
* 3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java          1065      manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

EDITED:
Scala is now abailable for Java 8 :-)

see http://www.scala-lang.org/news/2013/09/18/release-notes-v2.10.3-RC2.html

Comment: This works. Thanks !

Comment: Amazing, works now.