# Scala repl throws error

Tags: java, scala, read-eval-print-loop

When I type `scala` on the terminal to start the repl, it throws this error

```
scala> [init] error: error while loading AnnotatedElement, 
class file '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar
(java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement.class)' 
is broken (bad constant pool tag 15 at byte 2713)
```

When I hit <kbd>enter</kbd> and type `println("hello, world")`, it again throws this

```
error: error while loading CharSequence, 
class file '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar
(java/lang/CharSequence.class)' is broken
(bad constant pool tag 15 at byte 1501)
```

I am using `Ubuntu 14.04` and `java -version` gives

```
java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)
```

Comment: What version of Scala do you have?

Comment: scala -version gives `Scala code runner version 2.9.2 -- Copyright 2002-2011, LAMP/EPFL`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compilation failed: error while loading AnnotatedElement, ConcurrentMap, CharSequence from Java 8 under Scala 2.10?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24197836/compilation-failed-error-while-loading-annotatedelement-concurrentmap-charseq)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala REPL startup error “class file is broken”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18842985/scala-repl-startup-error-class-file-is-broken)

Comment: In addition to updating the Scala version, I also had to update the SBT version in the project's properties to fix this.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Either update to a newer scala version (2.10.3+) or downgrade java to java 6/7. As you have seen in the output, 2.9.2 was here long before java 8 was introduced (`Copyright 2002-2011, LAMP/EPFL`), so they don't work well together.

[This duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18842985/298389) contains exact instructions on ubuntu's java downgrade.

Comment: It feels to be logically impossible to ancestor to be duplicate of its successor (this one). That's why your flag that [far earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18842985/scala-repl-startup-error-class-file-is-broken) is duplicate (see "the question is asked before and (but not OR) already has an answer") of this one is a bit inaccurate. But you're right in a fact that current post has explicit answer whilst the earlier has implicit one and _de jure_ is unanswered.

Comment: @ghoshak I generally prefer older questions, but, yeah, closed that one because it had no accepted answers and existing question proposed only one way to solve problem. This post had a better chances in this perspective.

Comment: Yeah, your side are proper too but where have you been six months ago.

Comment: I don't understand why 2.10.3 is a newer version than 2.9.2 ?

Comment: @code4j it's like apartments #3 on 10th floor are higher than apartments #2 on 9th floor.

Answer (score 13):

remove the scala 2.9.2 using terminal

```
 sudo apt-get remove scala
```

download the latest scala from [scala website](http://www.scala-lang.org/download/)

Installation instruction are giving on this [link](http://www.scala-lang.org/download/install.html)

Comment: I installed scala 2.11.6 . don't forget to set the environment variable for scala for global access.

Answer (score 1):

You might have to run it with JDK 7 or 6

Comment: by setting the environment variable for example: `export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/`

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading JDK version to 7 solved this issue for me. 
Here is the solution:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/761127/how-do-i-install-openjdk-7-on-ubuntu-16-04-or-higher

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).