# error while loading CharSequence (scala 2.11.4)

Tags: linux, scala, sbt

They suggested me to update scala so I did it:

```
$ scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.11.4 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL
```

But this error remains:

```
my_project $ sbt 
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
[info] Loading project definition from /home/alex/Documents/projects/android/my_app123/sub_project1/project
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/alex/Documents/projects/android/my_app123/sub_project1/project/target/scala-2.9.2/sbt-0.12/classes...
[error] error while loading CharSequence, class file '/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_05/jre/lib/rt.jar(java/lang/CharSequence.class)' is broken
[error] (bad constant pool tag 15 at byte 1501)
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? q
```

So the error is the same. And also for some reason it has `...target/scala-2.9.2/sbt-0.12/classes` in it path, why is it using scala 2.9.2. I tried deleting the directory `target` but it appeared again with the same scala 2.9.2.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scala repl throws error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24517761/scala-repl-throws-error)

Comment: @SergeyLagutin, - Scala 2.11.4!!!!!

Comment: Can you post your build.sbt also. What is your sbt version?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp scala 2.11 has experimental support for java 8 ([scala-lang.org](http://scala-lang.org/news/2.11.1#required_java_version))

Answer (score 1):

The version of Scala installed on your system is irrelevant if you use sbt. What matters is that the following setting be present in your `build.sbt` file:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.4"
```

Comment: on my Mac machine it compiled without changing anything in the project. Why?

Comment: Because your Mac has a JDK 7?

Comment: It didn't pan out and it keeps creating the folder `.../project/target/scala-2.9.2/sbt-0.12/classes...`

Comment: That's "normal": it's for sbt itself, and apparently your project uses sbt 0.12.something. That's quite old. I recommend upgrading to 0.13.5 at least. It might help ... or not.