# How to fix broken class file error?

Tags: java, scala, ubuntu, stanford-nlp

I am trying to use [Stanford Topic Modeling Toolbox](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tmt/tmt-0.4/). I have Scala 2.12, Java version 1.8.0_111, sbt installed as stated in their [website](http://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html).

Now when I run: `java -jar tmt-0.4.0.jar example-0-test.scala`

I get following error message:

```
error: error while loading CharSequence, class file '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar(java/lang/CharSequence.class)' is broken
(bad constant pool tag 18 at byte 10)
```

I searched about this error. [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18842985/scala-repl-startup-error-class-file-is-broken), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24517761/scala-repl-throws-error) describes multiple java versions running and incompatible versions of Java and Scala. I do not have those problem.

Why is the error message being shown? How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

From the project's page:

> TMT was written during 2009-10 in what is now a quite old version of Scala, using a linear algebra library that is also no longer developed. Some people still use it and find it a friendly piece of software for LDA and Labeled LDA models, and more power to you, but at this point we really can't offer any support or fix any problems. Sorry about that.

It appears that it doesn't support newer versions of Scala, that were compatible with Java 1.8.

So you should install Java 1.6 runtime which should allow you to run this software.